# Mex works under Linux but not under Windows

Tags: c++, c, linux, matlab, cuda

I have encountered a very strange issue with one of my mex-files. It behaves differently on Linux and Windows. On the first one it works well (the mex uses CUDA cufft and kernels of my own), but under Windows I get

- cufft allocation failures, which I fixed
- unachieved calculations even after the first fix.

The main mex function is in a .cu , I compile it on a PC with the 6.5 toolkit and VS 2012 Pro for Windows. Under Linux I compile it with gcc and mex command.

For both platforms I use dynamic linking, 64bits Release, and openMP dynamic linking for Windows.
The Windows version does not always fail. At the beginning I thought it could be a memory allocation error, but now I believe it is a CUDA grid parameters error since some of my arrays are not filled.

My questions are the following

1. on Windows, are there different kernel dimensions than Linux ? (unprobable but ...)
2. Can the MATLAB 2013b be an issue ? (I ship the mex to Matlab 2014a users)
3. Are there other well-known differences in c++ or CUDA programming between Linux and Windows ?

Thanks in advance,

Julien

Comment: There are no differences in kernel dimension limits between linux and windows.  I don't think there is enough information here to answer your second question.  For your third question, it's very broad.  Yes there are differences, such as the WDDM timeout issue under windows which is not present in the same form under linux.  But properly written CUDA code should behave approximately the same way under windows or linux.  Are you doing proper error checking in your code?  You might want to provide a complete example of what you are doing.  I think the close votes are reflecting the lack of info.